# ADF af:query reset table on "Reset"

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am fairly new to the ADF, and I am trying to figure out how to reset the entire table on "Reset" with af:query Component.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line in af:table

```
  <af:column id="c165"   align="center" rowHeader="true" width="10" />
```

Make it as the first column, there will be a small pen when click on , it will clear the filter